# Error when running `carthage update`: xcodebuild: error: Scheme DVR-watchOS is not currently configured for the clean action

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8, carthage

I just upgraded my Xcode to version `8.0`. I am working with a project that is a year old (originally written in Swift `2.1`) and that uses Carthage.

I want to install the dependencies, so I am running `carthage update`. After running this, I get the following output:

```
$ carthage update
*** Fetching Nimble
*** Fetching DVR
*** Fetching Quick
*** Fetching ListKit
*** Fetching Result
*** Fetching Argo
*** Checking out Argo at "v3.1.0"
*** Checking out DVR at "56738677fddd560c5ab96a15b172db818e4c22d4"
*** Checking out ListKit at "1.0.0"
*** Checking out Nimble at "v4.1.0"
*** Checking out Quick at "v0.9.3"
*** Downloading Result.framework binary at "3.0.0"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/n0/t0tg9zrd3ms5kd4bzpnz9dww0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.WwnJ6q.log
*** Building scheme "Argo-iOS" in Argo.xcworkspace
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Unable to open project file '.../TripPlanner/Carthage/Checkouts/Argo/Argo Playground.playground' in workspace '.../TripPlanner/Carthage/Checkouts/Argo/Argo.xcworkspace'.
A shell task (/usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -project .../TripPlanner/Carthage/Checkouts/DVR/DVR.xcodeproj -scheme DVR-watchOS -configuration Release CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES clean -showBuildSettings) failed with exit code 66:
xcodebuild: error: Scheme DVR-watchOS is not currently configured for the clean action.
```

This is what my `Cartfile` looks like:

```
github "thoughtbot/Argo"
github "venmo/DVR" "master"
github "antitypical/Result"
github "Ben-G/ListKit"
```

I'm a bit lost and don't really know how to further debug this. Does anyone have a hint on what I can do to find out more info about the issue?

Comment: Hi, Did you figurate ?